# PostgreSQL: How to change log_min_duration_statement so that the change takes effect?

Tags: postgresql

I'm not able to change log_min_duration_statement setting. I connected to postges and tried:

```
select setting from pg_settings where name = 'log_min_duration_statement';
-1
alter system set log_min_duration_statement = 0;
select setting from pg_settings where name = 'log_min_duration_statement';
-1
```

Obviously nothing changed; what am I doing wrong?
Thank you, Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `alter system` you need to reload the configuration.

```
select pg_reload_conf();
```

To debug things like that, you can verify where where the current values comes from by looking at the columns `source_file` and `source_line` from the view `pg_settings`

Comment: After `alter system` command and `pg_reload_conf()` , settings still point to the older value. `source_file` and `source_line` both are `null`. What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have been unable to solve this with `alter system` then try to change directly in `postgresql.conf`. I have previously tried with `alter`, `update`, restart server but nothing.

When I've tried directly editing `postgresql.conf` and restarting I've seen in `pg_settings` 0 (was -1 previously).

Just remove `#` before line `log_min_duration_statement` and change `-1` to `0`.

In file is this `#log_min_duration_statement = -1`  and should be this
`log_min_duration_statement = 0`.

I am not sure why you made this change but take care because some other settings are linked to this one. e.g. `log_statement` is probably `none` and should be `ddl` or `all`.

Comment: Thanks for changes which weren't necessary, but ow this isn't answer. I did practice test and he has to take care also for some other parameters and not only for log_min_....